# Invalid character in identifier using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using python3 and selenium chrome driver and I want to have the script go to a url click some buttons etc.. which it already does then open a new tab and go to the same url again.

I have looked up on how to switch tabs in selenium and this is the line of code I got (note I am using a mac):

```
driver.find_element_­by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
```

I imported

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

And so whenever I run the script I get this error `"Invalid character in identifier"` and the by_tag_name in the script gets highlighted red.

Comment: No these are not solutions and they are in javascript @DebanjanB

Comment: The relevant part of the HTML is needed to find a good and stable solution for your question.

Comment: @Frank I dont Understand?? ^^

Answer (score 0):

I copied your Code in my Eclipse Environment and there appears a minus sign between the underscore and by (_-by) which is not visible in the code in your question. Can you remove that minus sign? And if succeeded can you try to run your code again?